# Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit does not boot after sudo apt upgrade

Tags: 16.04, boot, upgrade, 32-bit

I installed latest Ubuntu 16.04 on my 32-bit laptop. Clean install, erasing other operating systems. Everything was fine, I was able to reboot after the installation was finished. No other actions with the new operating system were made.

After that, I ran the command: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, waited until it finished and then I rebooted again. After that the system is not booting.

[image]

Every time the last message is `Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...`.

I can enter a virtual console with Ctrl+Alt+F1, but don't know what to do there. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`did not help. It said nothing to upgrade, and after rebooting it hangs again.

After removing `quiet splash` on `/etc/default/grub` in hangs with other message:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBsVL.jpg)

Now the last message is `Write protecting the kernel text: 8504k`, or `Starting WPA supplicant...`, the last message varies.

Comment: finish the update with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: did not helped, it said nothing to upgrade, after reboot hangs again

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to disable plymouth. Having acces to the console it is easy.

1. Log in the console.
2. Edit `/etc/default/grub` (as root, for example `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`)
3. Change the line

   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
   to

   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`
4. And then update grub and reboot

   `sudo update-grub && sudo reboot`

Comment: now it hangs with other message, I updated the question

Comment: These new messages are not bad and it is not clear why boot is not continuing. Had your upgrade finished successfully? Please try in the console `sudo aptitude clean  && sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude full-upgrade`. I am sure `aptitude` is smarter than `apt-get`.